# Multidimensional array and dllhijacking

Tags: c, windows, dll, multidimensional-array

I'am currently working on a tool which checks if your apps are vulnerable to dllhijacking.
Anyway, there's a section in my code which doesn't look very elegant.
Now there are just two sets, but I want to add some more. Is there another way
instead of just adding for loops for each set?

```
LPSTR szFileExtWireShark[] = {"airpcap.dll", ".bfr", ".enc", ".fdc", ".pcap", ".pcapng", ".syc", NULL};
LPSTR szFileExtWin7[] = {"wab32res.dll", ".contact", ".group", ".p7c", ".vcf", NULL};

int loadSets(LPSTR szFileName, LPSTR szPath) {
  int counter;
  for(counter=1; szFileExtWireShark[counter] != NULL; counter++) {
 checkExt(szFileName, szPath, szFileExtWireShark[counter], szFileExtWireShark[0]);
  }
  for(counter=1; szFileExtWin7[counter] != NULL; counter++) {
 checkExt(szFileName, szPath, szFileExtWin7[counter], szFileExtWin7[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using single loop

```
 LPSTR szFileExtWireShark[] = {"airpcap.dll", ".bfr", ".enc", ".fdc", ".pcap", ".pcapng", ".syc", NULL};
    LPSTR szFileExtWin7[] = {"wab32res.dll", ".contact", ".group", ".p7c", ".vcf", NULL};

    int loadSets(LPSTR szFileName, LPSTR szPath) {
      int counter;
      for(counter=1; (szFileExtWireShark[counter] != NULL && szFileExtWin7[counter] != NULL); counter++) {
    if(szFileExtWireShark[counter] != NULL)
     checkExt(szFileName, szPath, szFileExtWireShark[counter], szFileExtWireShark[0]);
    if(szFileExtWin7[counter] != NULL)
     checkExt(szFileName, szPath, szFileExtWin7[counter], szFileExtWin7[0]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: great answer. how do you want to keep the sets organised??